# How to get the "Live DOM panel" in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web?

Tags: visual-studio, dom

I'm having trouble seeing the "Live DOM panel". I'm new to Visual Studio and is following a  training for it through a book. The "Live DOM panel" never shows up after I open a blank Asp.Net page. I tried the method I found online that says to start debug, then go to Debug > Windows > DOM explorer, but there is no DOM Explorer either when I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Visual Studio doesn't have Live DOM panel. It is present in Blend that installed with Visual Studio together.

You could check more information about [Live DOM panel there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/jj129409)